# NumberLinePlot issue depending on number of elements being plotted

Tags: plotting

When evaluating this:

```
Table[n -> NumberLinePlot[{Range[n], Range[n]+.1}], {n, 4}]
```

we get this output:

[image]

Why is it different for n=2? Looks like a bug to me. Is there a workaround ?

This was evaluated with Mathematica 10.1 under Windows 7.

Comment: I think the $n=2$ case is unique in that the pairs of values are interpreted as the two *intervals* $[1, 2]$ and $[1.1, 2.1]$. Compare with `NumberLinePlot[{ {{1, 2}}, {{1.1, 2.1}} }]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarcoB says in the comments this is because the $n=2$ case is being interpreted as a set of two intervals rather than two separate intervals (where "interval" can also mean "points").

Functions like `ListLinePlot` have an option setting like `DataRange -> All | Automatic` to distinguish between cases like this but `NumberLinePlot` does not seem to have anything similar.

However as per the first example in the **Scope > Data** section of the documentation the solution is to wrap `List` around the first number line:

```
Table[NumberLinePlot[{{Range[n]}, Range[n] + 0.1}], {n, 4}]
```